# laravel 5.4, where to put controllers, models, views and routes?

Tags: laravel, view, controller

Having gone through numerous laravel tutorials and examples, i have seen source code with controllers, models and views in very different directories.

The question is, where should they go, and how does the system (which presumably requires convention) work if they are put in a different place?

E.g. [the official laravel quick-start projec](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart)t puts them in:

```
app/Http/Controllers/xxxControler.php
app/Http/routes.php
resources/views/xxx.blade.php
Cant find where it has put the models.
```

However, the [simple laravel crud master tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers) puts them here:

```
app/controllers/xxxControler.php
app/models/xxx.php
app/routes.php
app/views/xxx/create.blade.php
app/views/xxx/edit.blade.php
```

**Controllers**

If you look in the 5.4 documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers) it says controllers should go in app/Http/Controllers.

If this is the case, how did the latter example work (as the controller files are in the "wrong" dir, and I assume that laravel, like grails, relies on convention over configuration)?

The latter example directories seem much more logical than the official place, as a controller has nothing to do with Http - its part of the app logic.

**Models**

The [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections) mentions that "models typically live in the app directory".  This implies they can be put put in app/models, which is good.

**views**

Unfortunately, the official documentation says they have to go in resources/views.  Again, this would be far more logical to have views, controllers and models all being together as sub directories of app, as per the second example above. Is it possible, and advisable, to use this logical, but unofficial structure?  as a beginner, I have difficulty in finding the models, views and controllers as they are put in 3 different directory paths with no obvious logic.

**routes**
The official documentation says that routes should go in routes/web.php. I have not found an example project using this convention - I have seen them in app/routes.php, and app/http/routes.php.  Assuming its ok to put them in random places under app, how does one configure where the routes definition files go?

Answer (score 3):

### For Laravel version ^5.4

#### Controllers should be in this directory

```
app/Http/Controllers/xxxController.php
```

#### Models should be in this directory

```
app/xxx.php
```

#### Views should be in this directory

```
resources/views/xxx.blade.php
```

#### Routes should be in this directory

```
routes/web.php // for web routes
routes/api.php // for api routes
```

---

**These are all recommended places to put controllers, models, views and routes. You are free to modify everything of course!**

Older versions of Laravel have different places for Controllers, Models, Views and Routes. Check the documentation where they should be.

The thing is that you must recognize the Laravel version because Laravel went through many changes between years 2011 and 2016...

That link in your question for example is from year 2013 which is very old.

And I strongly recommend you to follow the Laracasts tutorials at laracasts.com

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have inherited a project which has everthing in different directories to this, but I am still able to run it with laravel 5.4. How does it know where to get the routes for example, which are not in routes/web.php but in app/routes.php?  I.e. I am used to grails which you put stuff in the right place and it just works.  Here people seem to put stuff anywhere and it still works, which implies its using configuration rather than convention to define the locations, but I dont see this configuration?

Comment: It's because of Laravels IoC Container, they made it so that it checks also the app/Http/routes.php file....try debugging the code and you will see

Comment: I would suggest adding somewhere to your answer that these are merely the defaults, where things *should* be is largely a matter of opinion. For example, I like to create a new directory called "app/Models" with almost every new project I work on.